# Focusout jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

i got the label of errore when i excute this as i use a time picker with a form field sharepoint control so

this is my code of jquery validation

```
    $("input[id*='ffEnTime']").focusout(function () {
        if ($("input[id*='ffEnTime']").val().trim() == "") {
            $("span[id*='lblEntTime']").show();
            $("span[id*='lblEntTime']").text("Write Entry Time");
        }
        else {
            $("span[id*='lblEntTime']").hide();
        }
    });
```

and the code of timepicker that i use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Start Validation at the after form loaded
    $("input[id*='ffPltNo']").attr("maxlength", "4");
    $("input[id*='ffIDNumber']").attr("maxlength", "10");
    $("input[id*='ffEnTime']").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    $("input[id*='ffEnTime']").attr("readOnly", "true");

    $("input[id*='ffEnTime']").timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm p',
        minTime: '06:30:00', // 11:45:00 AM,
        maxHour: 24,
        maxMinutes: 30,
        startTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 06, 0, 0), // 3:00:00 PM - noon
        interval: 30
    });
```

so it's look like this
[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpeVi.png)

the errore is come because when i click on any time to choose it'll first focus out then the validation will execute finally it'll choose the time in that case i have to chose again to let the label disapper

any suggestions to replace focus out with something better?

I tried on change but doesn't work with me.

Comment: Can you put up a https://jsfiddle.net/ with the minimal html and code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did u try

```
 $("input[id*='ffEnTime']").on('input',function () {
//your validation function here
})
```